# Accessing a containing object from with in its method?

Tags: javascript

In the snippet below, an object literal holds properties, one of which is a method that needs access to the the object literal.

However, b.c. it is only used as an event handler callback, `this` always points to the element that triggered the event.

I need to access the containing object.

Otherwise, I'm forced to put a function in a function which seems odd.

```
/***************************************************************************************************
**MSimMenu - simple drop down menu
*/


    NS.parsel({
        Name: 'MSimMenu',
        E: {
            hold_name:         '#hold_name',
            wrap_bottom:       '#wrap_bottom'
        },
        A: {
            time_out_id:        null,
            TIME_DELAY:         1000
        },

        // in mouseout this points to the element that triggered the event
        // need access to containing object

        mouse_out: function () {
            this.A.time_out_id = NS.setTimeout(this.hideBottom, this.A.TIME_DELAY);
        },
        init: function () {
            var self = this;

            // tempoaray fix - function in function seems odd

            function mouse_out() {
                self.A.time_out_id = NS.setTimeout(self.hideBottom, self.A.TIME_DELAY);
            }

            self.E.hold_name.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
                NS.clearTimeout(self.A.time_out_id);
                self.showBottom();
            }, false);
            self.E.wrap_bottom.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
                NS.clearTimeout(self.A.time_out_id);
            }, false);
            self.E.wrap_bottom.addEventListener("mouseout", mouse_out, false);
            self.E.hold_name.addEventListener("mouseout", mouse_out, false);
        },
        showBottom: function () {
            this.E.wrap_bottom.style.visibility = 'visible';
        },
        hideBottom: function () {
            this.E.wrap_bottom.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    });
```

---

**Final Code Using Bind**

```
NS.parsel({
    Name: 'MSimMenu',
    E: {
        hold_name:         '#hold_name',
        wrap_bottom:       '#wrap_bottom'
    },
    A: {
        time_out_id:        null,
        TIME_DELAY:         1000
    },
    init: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.E.hold_name.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
            NS.clearTimeout(self.A.time_out_id);
            self.showBottom();
        }, false);
        self.E.wrap_bottom.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
            NS.clearTimeout(self.A.time_out_id);
        }, false);
        self.E.wrap_bottom.addEventListener("mouseout", self.mouse_out.bind(self), false);
        self.E.hold_name.addEventListener("mouseout", self.mouse_out.bind(self), false);
    },
    mouse_out: function () {
        this.A.time_out_id = NS.setTimeout(this.hideBottom, this.A.TIME_DELAY);
    },
    showBottom: function () {
        this.E.wrap_bottom.style.visibility = 'visible';
    },
    hideBottom: function () {
        this.E.wrap_bottom.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have seen alot of people create a variable to assign the object to and then use the variable.

```
var that = {
    myfunc:function(){
        console.log(that)
    }
};
NS.parsel(that);
```

Comment: right. i definitely hope you wouldn't create "that" scoped to window. i prefer closure based classes. this allows me to have "private" functions, public functions, and run in a scoped environment. a side benefit to that is all the "gee is this running in the right context" questions disappear. anyway, im glad you found an answer that suits your needs... :)

Comment: `NS.parsel()` is enclosed in an IIFE ( Immediately Invoked Function Expression )

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways you can get what you want.

One trick you can do is to not use the `mouse_out` function directly, but provide a helper function like `get_mouse_out()` that returns a bound version of the function.

```
var myobject = {
   data:"Some data",
   _mouse_out: function() { console.log(this.data); }
   get_mouse_out: function() {
     var self = this;
     return function(){ return Function.apply(self._mouse_out,self,arguments); }
   }
}

//Example call back using function.
function do_callback(fn) { fn(); }

//This doesn't work.
do_callback( myobject._mouse_out);

//But this does
do_callback( myobject.get_mouse_out() );
```

EDIT: Improved version inlining _mouse_out and using bind.

```
var myobject = {
   data:"Some data",
   get_mouse_out: function() {
     function _mouse_out() { console.log(this.data); }
     return _mouse_out.bind(this);
   }
}

//Example call back using function.
function do_callback(fn) { fn(); }

//But this does
do_callback( myobject.get_mouse_out() );
```

If you're willing to have `init` be called as setup before `mouse_out` is used then you can do this.

```
var myobject = {
   data:"Some data",
   init: function() {
     function _mouse_out() { console.log(this.data); }
     this.mouse_out = _mouse_out.bind(this);
   }
}

myobject.init();
fn( myobject.mouse_out );
```

Finally there's a nice variant on Shanimals that works a similar way, but provides encapsulation.

```
 NS.parcel( (function(){
    var myobj = {};
    myobj.data = "Some data";
    myobj.mouse_out = function(){ console.log(myobj.data); }
    return myobj;
  })() 
 );
```

Comment: The solution is much simpler.  I've posted the modified code in the question.

Comment: Yep, use of `Function.bind` is neater than what I've written (but equivalent). The other key difference is that its left to the user to do the binding of the `mouse_out` function which is easy to miss. (Which is fine for your use case since its happening inside another member function).

Answer (score 1):

I actually like moving most of the logic into the `init` method. Provides nice encapsulation with an easy way to declare public and private methods/variables. For example:

```
NS.parsel({
  init: function() {

    var self = this;

    //public instance variable
    self.Name = 'MSimMenu';

    //private instance variables
    var A = {
      time_out_id:        null,
      TIME_DELAY:         1000
    };
    var E = {
        hold_name:         '#hold_name',
        wrap_bottom:       '#wrap_bottom'
    };

    //public instance method
    self.showBottom = function () {
        E.wrap_bottom.style.visibility = 'visible';
    };

    //private instance method
    E.wrap_bottom.addEventListener("mouseout", mouse_out, false);
    function mouse_out() {
      A.time_out_id = NS.setTimeout(self.hideBottom, A.TIME_DELAY);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @pure_code.mom Not quite, in this version `x.showBottom` is only created after `x.init()` is called, not when the object is first created (as in the original version).

Comment: ...this is almost a form of lazy initialization?